# Unable To Extract HTML Data Via Android / Java

Tags: java, android, jquery, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm attempting to scrape a bit of data off a website using Android/Java/JSoup but I'm unable to update my textview with the table data from the url shown below.

I believe I've done almost everything correct regarding my implementation of JSOUP to parse the table data however for some strange reason I still cannot view the data I'm attempting to acquire when I execute the following:

SOURCE:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    final String URL = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=";lname=&fname=";
String tr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(URL);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Elements tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid");
                Element th = doc.select("tr").first();
                Element firstTh = th.select("th").first();
                title = firstTh.text();
        }   catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should your URL string really start with "h_ttp://h_tp://"? I added those underscores so it wouldn't turn into a link.

Comment: I fixed that... it's still not working

Comment: cant see any class `datagrid` in the page

Comment: also the url seems to be wrong "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname="*;lname=&fname=";*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can do the parsing for you. At least it works in Java. Just change the System.out.println part to something else, to display the data on the UI. You can use cells.get(i) to get the content of the cells of the table.

```
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
        Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

        Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
        for (Element row : tableRows) {
            Elements cells = row.select("td");
            if (cells.size() >0) {
                System.out.println(cells.get(0).text()+"; "+cells.get(1).text()+"; "+cells.get(2).text()+"; "+cells.get(3).text());
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be your issue:

```
final String URL = "http://http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=";
```

Try:

```
final String URL = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=";
```

Comment: Then I would set some break points and use the debugger to determine if the `title` variable is getting the data. If not, then there is something wrong with the scraping.

Comment: Step over that, not into it.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

its because your url is wrong:

```
final String URL = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=";lname=&fname=";
```

it should change to

```
String url = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=FOO&fname=BAR";
```

here are the paremeters name and surname you have to search for:

```
lname=FOO&fname=BAR;
```

if you change this it will work, if you want try this for testing:

```
http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=bob
```